# Queue::later() not working on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, queue

I am studying Laravel framework and I am facing some problems with queues. Laravel provides a unified API to work with queues and I am taking a look into it. One of the methods that Laravel provides is `Queue::later(DateTime|int $delay, string $job, mixed $data = '', string $queue = null);`

So, I implemented my job class:

```
<?php

class SendEmail {
    public function send($job, $data) {
        Log::info('JOB: ' . $job->getName());
        Log::info('DATA: ' . $data['message']);
    }
}
```

Above, I log on a file, the parameters received. Just to know if it's working or not. My controller calls the job this way using Queue API:

```
<?php

class MyControllerController extends BaseController {

    function index() {
        LOG::debug('Index action STARTED');
        $date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(2);
        Queue::later($date, 'SendEmail@send', array('message' => 'MY MESSAGE!'));
        $view = View::make('index');
        LOG::debug('Index action FINISHED');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Take a look that I am using `Queue::later()`. I expected that method `send()` of class `SendEmail` would be executed after 2 minutes.
Well, I finished to implement a blank view and set up the route. Then I made a GET request to my controller and I went to check the log file.

I saw this when I opened the log file:

```
[2014-10-02 16:23:11] production.DEBUG: Index action STARTED [] []
[2014-10-02 16:23:11] production.INFO: JOB:  [] []
[2014-10-02 16:23:11] production.INFO: DATA: MY MESSAGE! [] []
[2014-10-02 16:23:11] production.DEBUG: Index action FINISHED [] []
```

Everything executed at same time, inclusive the job. The `Queue::later()` is not delaying the execution. I think my log file should be:

```
[2014-10-02 16:23:11] production.DEBUG: Index action STARTED [] []
[2014-10-02 16:23:11] production.DEBUG: Index action FINISHED [] []
[2014-10-02 16:25:11] production.INFO: JOB:  [] []
[2014-10-02 16:25:11] production.INFO: DATA: MY MESSAGE! [] []
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, just found my mistake. I am using `sync` driver, which means the job is executed when the job is created. I opened my `/app/config/queue.php` and found:

```
'sync' => array(
    'driver' => 'sync',
),
```

I will try with `beanstalkd`.