# trigger queue jobs without waiting sending email in Laravel v4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4

I working on user registration tasks and my target is to send welcome email after 30 minutes of registration of user But I don't know that how this process will work because every time I receive total jobs in Queue is 1.
Below is my method to register user and push job in queue but I don't want to wait until email send.

```
public function register_process($inuts){
    if(User::insert($inuts)){
        $date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(15);
        Queue::later($date, 'HomeController@testQueueJobs', array('message' =>$inuts['message']));
}}

public function testQueueJobs($job,$data){
        echo 'Total Jobs In Queue:'.count($job);die;
}
```

Now I am confused that how this job will execute after successful user registration with out sending email.
Please help or refer any helpful demo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What driver are you using? https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#configuration

If you're using `sync` for local development, I believe jobs are queued up immediately. You need to use a driver that supports a delay.

Examples:

1. [Queue::later() not working on Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168350/queuelater-not-working-on-laravel)
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-get-later-to-delay-queued-emails-in-laravel-54